# flask unittest - make multi fixture without loop

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing, flask

we have multiple factory data in phpunit
`factory(User::class,4)->create();`
that we can create 4 user data model in testing environment

but i use this loop in flask unittest:
`user = User(email=factory.email(),username=factory.word())
      for index in range(5):
          db.session.add(user)
      db.session.commit()`

is there any same way for this??

Comment: Is there any way to do what? Create five users and add them to a database? It looks like you've got it already. Are you asking if there's a one-line solution?

Comment: yes, i mean without loop and in one-line